# Connect-AzAccount sends warning to console

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

**I have the command**

```
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $TenantId
```

When this runs as a pwsh step in my CI pipeline I get the below warning:

> The provided service principal secret or certificate password will be included in the 'keystore.cache' file found in the user profile ( /home/vsts/.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate protections.

How to mitigate this?
Does `Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null` work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think `Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null` works.

I have a debug yaml to check the process

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: before login get .Azure folder
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $p = Test-Path -Path '/home/vsts/.Azure'
      if($p){
        Get-ChildItem -Path '/home/vsts/.Azure'
      }
      else{
        Write-Output 'file not exist'
      }

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: install az module
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: login with sp
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      # Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
      $SecureStringPwd = 'xxxx' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
      $pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'xxxx', $SecureStringPwd
      Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant 'xxxxx'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: after login get .Azure folder
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $p = Test-Path -Path '/home/vsts/.Azure'
      if($p){
        Get-ChildItem -Path '/home/vsts/.Azure'
      }
      else{
        Write-Output 'file not exist'
      }

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: get az context
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-AzContext
```

comment and dis-comment the `Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process` to check the warning message and `get az context` task result.